# Question about σ -algebra generated by family of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and consider the function $f(\,\cdot\,;y ): X\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$. Let $\sigma(f_y):=\{f^{-1}(S;y):S\in \mathcal{B}\}$.

Is it possible to construct a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma\supseteq\{f^{-1}(S;y):S\in \mathcal{B},y\in\mathbb{R}^m\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is nothing to "construct" here, because $\Sigma$ is already defined.

Maybe you meant to ask whether $\Sigma=\bigcup_{y\in\mathbb R^m}\sigma(f_y)$ can be recognized as a $\sigma$-algebra.

In general the answer is "no", because a union of $\sigma$-algebras is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra.

It is closed under complements but not under countable unions.

Sets $A,B$ might exist with $A\in\sigma(f_{y_0})$ and $B\in\sigma(f_{y_1})$ such that for every $y\in\mathbb R^m$ we have $A\cup B\notin\sigma(f_{y})$.

Comment: "Actually there is nothing to "construct" here, because Σ is already defined." I've fixed that mistake.

Comment: For a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\Sigma$ there are two obvious candidates: the powerset of $X$ and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the union of $\sigma$-algebras that I mention in my answer. Gives that enough satisfaction if it comes to "constructing a $\sigma$-algebra"?